# CLI Cordova change ios build target

Tags: xcode, cordova, command-line-interface

I added in my iOS project 3 targets (with different provisioning, different plist and specific configurations).

- Target 1 --> MyApp-Info.plist
- Target 2 --> MyApp-2-Info.plist
- Target 3 --> MyApp-3-Info.plist

However, when I execute the command `cordova build ios` I can not choose the target to compile. It is always the target by default (Target 1).

In the logs of the Terminal, I have always the following line: 
`ProcessInfoPlistFile build/emulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist`

Is there a way to choose the target to compile? or a Xcode project configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `before_build` hook in combination with a shell variable to dynamically copy/rename the required `.plist` file to `MyApp-Info.plist`. Eg: `BUILD_TARGET=1 cordova build ios`. The before hook should then of course take `BUILD_TARGET` into account.